# Count changes from specific value within time period

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access query question.

In its simplified version, I have a table containing a (support) ticketid column, status column and a timestamp column. The timestamp column indicates when the (new) status was set for the ticket.

My final goal is to count the number of tickets that changed status FROM status 18 within a certain time frame. This includes tickets that got status 18 within the time frame and 'lost' it again, but also tickets that already had status 18 at the start of the time frame.

My intermediate query below obviously is not correct, as it returns too many records. It does not just compare to the next record (in time), but any record.

```
SELECT *
    FROM 
(SELECT tkhtimestamp, tkhticketid, tkhstatusid FROM tickethistory WHERE tkhstatusid NOT IN     (18) AND tkhtimestamp >= #3-jul-2014 9:00:00# AND tkhtimestamp <= #4-jul-2014 9:00:00#) AS new_status_records
    INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tkhtimestamp, tkhticketid, tkhstatusid FROM tickethistory WHERE  tkhstatusid  IN (18) AND tkhtimestamp <= #4-jul-2014 9:00:00#) AS old_status_records
    ON old_status_records.tkhticketid = new_status_records.tkhticketid AND old_status_records.tkhtimestamp < new_status_records.tkhtimestamp
```

Can someone please advise on this, as I cannot seem to get this done. Other efforts using max/min and group by failed as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea in using MAX/MIN and GROUP BY. For test data in [tickethistory]

```
tkhtimestamp         tkhticketid  tkhstatusid
-------------------  -----------  -----------
2014-07-02 10:00:00            1           10
2014-07-02 12:00:00            2           18
2014-07-03 13:30:00            1           18
2014-07-03 13:35:00            1           99
2014-07-03 15:00:00            2           99
```

the following query will extract the current and previous timestamp for each new history record of each ticket:

```sql
SELECT 
    curr.tkhticketid, 
    curr.tkhtimestamp AS curr_timestamp, 
    MAX(prev.tkhtimestamp) AS prev_timestamp
FROM
    tickethistory curr
    INNER JOIN
    tickethistory prev
        ON curr.tkhticketid = prev.tkhticketid
            AND curr.tkhtimestamp > prev.tkhtimestamp
GROUP BY    
    curr.tkhticketid, 
    curr.tkhtimestamp
```

It returns

```
tkhticketid  curr_timestamp       prev_timestamp     
-----------  -------------------  -------------------
          1  2014-07-03 13:30:00  2014-07-02 10:00:00
          1  2014-07-03 13:35:00  2014-07-03 13:30:00
          2  2014-07-03 15:00:00  2014-07-02 12:00:00
```

We can then join that back to the [tickethistory] table (twice) to retrieve the current and previous status values

```sql
SELECT
    tkh_curr.tkhticketid,
    tkh_curr.tkhtimestamp AS curr_timestamp,
    tkh_curr.tkhstatusid AS curr_status,
    tkh_prev.tkhtimestamp AS prev_timestamp,
    tkh_prev.tkhstatusid AS prev_status
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                curr.tkhticketid, 
                curr.tkhtimestamp AS curr_timestamp, 
                MAX(prev.tkhtimestamp) AS prev_timestamp
            FROM
                tickethistory curr
                INNER JOIN
                tickethistory prev
                    ON curr.tkhticketid = prev.tkhticketid
                        AND curr.tkhtimestamp > prev.tkhtimestamp
            GROUP BY    
                curr.tkhticketid, 
                curr.tkhtimestamp
        ) curr_prev
        INNER JOIN
        tickethistory tkh_curr
            ON tkh_curr.tkhticketid = curr_prev.tkhticketid
                AND tkh_curr.tkhtimestamp = curr_prev.curr_timestamp
    )
    INNER JOIN
    tickethistory tkh_prev
        ON tkh_prev.tkhticketid = curr_prev.tkhticketid
            AND tkh_prev.tkhtimestamp = curr_prev.prev_timestamp
```

returning

```
tkhticketid  curr_timestamp       curr_status  prev_timestamp       prev_status
-----------  -------------------  -----------  -------------------  -----------
          1  2014-07-03 13:30:00           18  2014-07-02 10:00:00           10
          1  2014-07-03 13:35:00           99  2014-07-03 13:30:00           18
          2  2014-07-03 15:00:00           99  2014-07-02 12:00:00           18
```

If you save that query in Access with a name like [qryTicketHistoryChanges] then you should be able to run other queries against it to pull out the specific information you need.

Comment: Truly impressive and well explained answer Gord ! Thank you.